# API Request works from web application but not from Postman

Tags: postman, bearer-token

In my web application I am making some `API` calls, they have a `Bearer Auth Token`, so I go to `Network` tab of Chrome and grab the URL Address and `Bearer token` and then paste them both in `Postman` and it is also a `GET` request.
But When I do that in Postman, I get `401 Unauthorized`, but it works in Chrome and I can see it on the Response Tab just fine.
What else should I set up in Postman?

Comment: If just the token doesn't allow you to access, then the API must be using some other header information to validate as well. Take all the browser headers and make the request, then remove them one by one until you can't make the request anymore. Of course, if you had access to the API code, then you could just go look at that and see what it's using.

Comment: Also, it's worth showing us what you're doing when you say you're "pasting them both in `Postman`" - what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @Adam yeah I think maybe there are more in the headers that I need to copy paste. By Copy Pasting I means I click on the Chrome's value, choose "copy value" and then paste it in Postman.

Comment: "paste it in Postman" - it's still not clear. In addition, In Postman you do auth headers a little differently than just paste them into the headers of the request. Click on the three dots next to your collection that your request is a part of and click "Edit" in the menu. Click `Authorization` and then select `Bearer Token`. Then drop your token in the place in the input on the right. Effectively, it's the same thing as an auth header, but it's a little easier to use the same auth across a bunch of requests in a collection, and prevent typos and things like that.

Comment: @Adam thanks, yep that's what I meant. I go to Authorization tab and selected Bearer Token type and copy paste the token from Chrome into Postman's text box.